# plt.gcf() doesn't show previous instance of a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

I want to save an instance of a plot into an object so that I can display it later by just calling that object.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
y1 = x
y2 = np.sin(x)

plt.plot(x, y1, linewidth=1, color = 'deepskyblue')
fig1 = plt.gcf()

plt.plot(x, y2, linewidth=1, color = 'red')
fig2 = plt.gcf()
```

In this example, I first draw a blue line (y1=x) and use `plt.gcf()` to save an instance of this plot in `fig1`. Then I add a red curve (y2=sin(x)) to the plot and use `plt.gcf()` again to save this plot in `fig2`. Now, I expect that when I call `fig1` I only get the blue line, and when I call `fig2` I get both lines. Like this (I'm in Jupyter):

```
fig1   # or fig1.show() if not in Jupyter
```

Only blue curve
[image: Only blue curve]

```
fig2
```

Both curves
[image: Both curves]

But, in reality, when I call `fig1` and `fig2`, both of them show both curves (like the second picture). Can someone please help how I can correctly get an instance of each plot so that I can display each of them later whenever I want?

Comment: use the object oriented API. https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html?highlight=object%20oriented#the-object-oriented-interface-and-the-pyplot-interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to force *matplotlib* to actually draw the figure by setting a `plot.show()` in your code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
y1 = x
y2 = np.sin(x)

plt.plot(x, y1, linewidth=1, color = 'deepskyblue')
plt.show()
fig1 = plt.gcf()

plt.plot(x, y2, linewidth=1, color = 'red')
plt.show()
fig2 = plt.gcf()
```

Using the function `plt.plot()` always plots to the current axis (if no axis is present, a new one is created).
You can also tell *matplotlib* explicitly to open a new figure:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
y1 = x
y2 = np.sin(x)

# open first figure
fig1 = plt.figure()
# plot
plt.plot(x, y1, linewidth=1, color = 'deepskyblue')

# open second figure
fig2 = plt.figure()
#plot
plt.plot(x, y2, linewidth=1, color = 'red')
```

Although this already fixes your problem, it is considered good practice to use an object-oriented version of this like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
y1 = x
y2 = np.sin(x)

# open first figure, axis
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
# plot
ax1.plot(x, y1, linewidth=1, color = 'deepskyblue')

# open second figure, axis
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
#plot
ax2.plot(x, y2, linewidth=1, color = 'red')
```

In all cases, you will get:
[image: output]

Now, why don't  you need `plt.show()` in the other approaches? Well, *matplotlib* by explicitly opening a new figure/axis, it is obvious that the previous axis is finished and can be drawn.

The last approach is the clearest as you tell exactly which figure and which axis you are considering.

Comment: Thanks so much. You are right, using the last option which is the object-oriented approach seems to be the best one and the clearest.